# Are there any extra steps for a Node.js express application using mongodb atlas deployed to Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, mongodb-atlas

I am making a node.js express application (express-generator in case that helps) that is deployed to Heroku. I am using an AWS atlas MongoDB cluster, and I am pretty new to this. I am using mongoose in my express app. I was wondering, is there anything I should do so that me running on my localhost in development or people who visit my website at the Heroku deployed can access and retrieve and send data with the site? I am simply doing a login, register, profile information functionality that stores in atlas.

I read a MongoDB [blog post](https://developer.mongodb.com/how-to/use-atlas-on-heroku/) about Heroku with MongoDB, but it did not really apply to me because they were not using mongoose but an npm lib called MongoDB?

I don’t really do anything like a development or production environment, I simply write the code, run it on my localhost, then it is deployed automatically to Heroku with a ci on every commit and push.

If this helps, my project structure and functionality are extremely similar to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Us-JwsZtAwA&t=1193s). Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell what issue exactly are you facing?

Comment: I am not exactly experiencing an issue with it, but am wondering if there is anything I miss out on or an issue a client might run into.